# Fetching/Retrieval of Data from CKAN?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fiware, ckan

How does CKAN fetch data from a database? How does it retrieve data from a Link while viewing it (when we are not using Datastore)?

I am using CKAN 2.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, CKAN does not fetch any data from an external database. This also means that, by default, you can only use the basic preview widgets that display the document at the resource's URL as plain text, image or an embedded web page. In that case, the resource document is not fetched by CKAN but by the user's browser via JavaScript.

If you want to use the more advanced preview widgets that support tables, filtering, etc. then the resource data needs to uploaded into CKAN's internal [DataStore](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html). This is typically done using the [DataPusher](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/), which automatically uploads new resource data into the DataStore. The DataPusher runs on the same server as CKAN, so in contrast to the basic default preview widgets this process happens on the server side.

Comment: What might be the purpose of Apache Solr then in CKAN ?

Comment: Solr is a search engine, and is used in CKAN to search for datasets and resources. That usually takes only the metadata into account (title, description, etc.). You can use [ckanext-extractor](https://github.com/stadt-karlsruhe/ckanext-extractor) to also include information from the actual resource data in the search index (full disclosure: I'm the author of ckanext-extractor).

Comment: what does postgresql database in CKAN holds ?? Only the user related information/organisation/dataset information??

Comment: PostgreSQL is the main database for CKAN and holds all persistent information (datasets, resources, users, organizations, DataStore data, etc.) aside from uploaded resource files. Solr is used only for searching, and data relevant for searching is indexed/duplicated there.